# Remove the last X specific characters from string

Tags: c#

What is the fastest way to remove the last two '0' in a string so the result to become 000110100111 ?

```
string text1 = "00011010001101";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet should do:

```
 string text1 = "00011010001101";

 int count = 2;

 string result = text1;
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
      result = result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf("0"), 1);
 }
```

PS. LINQ-way:

```
var result = Enumerable.Repeat("0", count)
            .Aggregate(text1, (text, charToRemove) => text.Remove(text.LastIndexOf(charToRemove), 1));
```

First parameter to Enumerable.Repeat is substring to remove, second parameter tells how many times it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way it to do it manually:

```
string text1 = "00011010001101";
int count=0;
for (int i = text1.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (text1[i] == '0')
    {
        text1 = text1.Remove(i, 1);
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 2)
        break;
}
```

The duration of this is 20 ticks. The other way with the usage of searching with `LastIndexOf()` needs 53 ticks.